# why can the agg..method use dictionaries with reversed syntax?

Tags: python, pandas

This is my first Python-related question so bear with me....

I'm doing the "data scientist with Python"-course at Datacamp. One of the current rows of code I'm supposed to complete looks like this:

```
print(____.groupby(____).agg({'income':'median'}))
```

And I guess this bothers me. This is "not" how that method is supposed to work according to the [documenation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.agg.html). Although it states dictionaries with arguments on the form "function:variable" can be passed as arguments (though annoyingly enough we have to infer this from the examples) it also states that the function must be the first argument and the variable the second. Why can the order be reversed in the above example?

Is the sequence of functions/columns in dictionaries passed as arguments totally arbitrary?

Comment: "it also states that the function must be the first argument and the variable the second.": where does it state that for a dictionary? Can you quote part of the sentence? I can't find it.

Comment: Did you try reversing the order in your example? Does it work?

Comment: It doesn't say that specifically of a dictionary. It states that in general the arguments must be passed in that sequence: DataFrame.agg(func=None, axis=0, *args, **kwargs)[source]¶

Comment: For a dict as the first argument to `agg()`, the documentation states: "dict of axis labels -> functions, function names or list of such.". That requires some parsing, but if you read "axis labels" as columns, the "->" as separating keys on the left and values on the right, and then "function names", you're back to your example code: key = column name, value = function name.

Comment: What do you mean " in general"? It says that the `func` can be a number of things, *including* a dictionary of 'axis names -> function (name)s'.

Comment: To answer your question: no, it is not arbitrary: column names need to be keys of the dict, function names (or functions themselves) need to be the corresponding values.

Answer (score 0):

the correct syntax is:

```
df.groupby('column_name').agg({"column_name": agg_func})
```

Comment: Note that a string for `agg_func`, being the name of a function, is also accepted.